# Highlighting a row once a parameter has been selected in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that has 3 parameters: `RaceDate`, `RaceCourse`, `SilksColours`. The `SilksColours` parameter is optional.

If the `SilksColours` parameter is selected I want to highlight the row in my report with the colour yellow, while all the other rows stay white.

Is this possible?

Comment: This seems like a basic SSRS task, but perhaps your question is lacking info? Can you [tell us what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and be specific about the problem you're having?

Comment: What you say the parameter is optional do you mean it accepts `NULL` values?

Comment: Good Morning, I think you are right Jereon I have explained myself right. I have 3 parameters:

Racedate - This must be selected
Racecourse - This Must be selected
Silkcolours - This does not need to be selected if the person doesn't want to, if not selected (or left blank) all rows will we be left white, however if a person selects a colour from the parameter drop down choice then where that colour appears on the report that row will be highlighted yellow and all other rows will be white.

I hope that this has clarified my question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each TextBox in the row you want to highlight, you need need to set the Background Color property to be expression-based and compare the parameter value to value in the row, something like:

```
=IIf(Fields!Colour.Value = Parameters!SilksColours.Value, "Yellow", "White")
```

Edit after comments:

OK, as you've noted there are two questions here.

**Parameter with default**

You have a requirement to have a multi-value parameter with the ability to specify no value in particular. You can't set up a multi-value to accept `NULL` values, so you need to add a catch all value to the DataSet. So base the parameter on values similar to the following:

[image]

Set a parameter up to use this DataSet and set the Default Value to *None*:

[image]

[image]

Now we have a parameter with a default, which will not highlight any rows, so users can just ignore if they want or choose values as required.

There is one minor annoyance here - the user can select *None* and other values as well, they aren't mutually exclusive, but it should be good enough.

**Highlighting rows**

Next step is to set the **Background Color** values for all required TextBoxes. Since multiple colours can be selected, we need to treat multi-value parameters differently from single ones, something like:

```
=IIf(InStr(Join(Parameters!Colour.Value, ","), Fields!Colour.Value) > 0
    , "Yellow"
    , "White")
```

So what we need to do is use the `JOIN` function to create a string list of selected values, then check if the row value is anywhere in that list. Put it all together to get the following:

The report will load straight away as the parameter has a default value, with no rows highlighted:

[image]

Choose one colour and the row is highlighted:

[image]

Choose multiple colours to highlight multiple rows:

[image]

Hopefully all this is what you're after!

Comment: Hi Ian

=IIf(Fields!SilksName.Value = Parameters!Colours.Value(0), "Yellow", "White")

This worked sort off, but I need to have the option of selecting 0 (default) or selecting many but when I do this is only shows me one highlighted field.

First Question - How do I get the parameter to deafault none
Second Question - How do I get the parameter to show me multiple highlighted cells when selected?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I fully understand... Is this a multi-value parameter? You'd have to update the expression in that case. For each cell you want to highlight you set the Background Color property to the expression. Can you please add a simplified example to your question to help demonstrate your requirements?

Comment: Hi Ian

These are my Parameters

Racedate - This must be selected

Racecourse - This Must be selected

Silkcolours - This does not need to be selected if the person doesn't want to, if not selected (or left blank) all rows will be left white, however if a person selects a colour from the parameter drop down choice then where that colour appears on the report that row will be highlighted yellow and all other rows will be white.

I hope that this has clarified my question. Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, this doesn't change the answer above. I still don't know if this is a single or multi-value parameter, whether NULLs are allowed, or the specific issues you are facing. Can you update your answer with screenshots showing the issue? Just a few rows should be enough. Please descibe exactly how the parameter is working, what expression you are using, what you are currently seeing and what you expect to see. Don't worry about anything that doesn't affect the problem at hand, e.g. other parameters.

Comment: Hi Ian I don't know how to paste screenshots into this website, but I will try to answer your questions: It is a multivalue parameter, the person has a choice of selecting no color or Black or Blue or Red or a combination of any colours this is the dataset for the parameter

SELECT SilksImages.id,SilksImages.Silks_Skey AS [SilksImages Silks_Skey],SilksImages.filestream_data,Silks.Silks_Skey AS [Silks Silks_Skey],Silks.SilksName
FROMSilks INNER JOIN SilksImages ON Silks.Silks_Skey = SilksImages.Silks_Skey

Comment: What I would like to happen is the person can leave the parameter blank and the report will run but also if the person wants to choose a color then where the color is in the report then highlight that row yellow, also i want them to be able to chooses multiple colors so if the choose red and black then both with highlight the corresponding rows.

Comment: OK, thanks for the extra info, I think I've got it now... Please see updated answer.